# C# to JAVA Code Equivalent (Remove Extra Space within the String)

Tags: java, string

What is the equivalent for this `C#` code in `Java`?

```
String newSTr = string.Join(" ", xString.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Basically the function trims all extra spaces (*trailing and spaces inside within the string*). Thanks

Let's say i have this examples:

```
I    have    this      string.      ==     I have this string.
    I have    this  string   .      ==     I have this string .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"I    have    this      string. ".replaceAll ("\\s\\s+", " ").trim ();
```

result: "I have this string."

```
"I    have    this      string. ".replaceAll ("  +", " ").trim ();
```

Works with leading/trailing whitespace too.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy to tell from the String API docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
String newStr = "TEST STRING ! @ # $";

newStr = newStr.replace(" ", "");
```

Important to note that this will only remove space characters to remove all whitespace you need to use a regular expression:

```
newStr = newStr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

**EDIT**

```
//replace all groups of whitespaces with a single whitespace
newStr = newStr.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: That is very easy and not what i want. I have updated my question. Your answer removes `ALL` not extra spaces.

Comment: You can get that functionality by just doing one more replace

Comment: Yup. Why not simply `newStr = newStr.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");` or `newStr = newStr.replaceAll(" +", " ");`?

Comment: @Alderath That is an excellent point, I have no idea why I didn't do that

Answer (score -1):

```
str = str.replace(" ", "");
```

or

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```